# Getting rows between date range is not working in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2

In SQL Server 2008R2 fetching data between two dates is not working.

I am using the following code to get rows from the `INVOICE` table where the `CREATED_DATE` is between `@startdate` and `@enddate`, which are the parameters I am sending to the stored procedure.

```
Select * 
from INVOICES INV 
where CONVERT(Varchar(10), INV.CREATED_DATE, 105)
      BETWEEN CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), @startdate, 105) 
          AND CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), @enddate, 105)
```

It is not working properly, driving me nuts..

What I am doing wrong?..

Comment: I could not understand why you are converting the dates to varchar for the query. Cannot you keep it as date only?

Comment: Iam doing this because in database INV.CREATED_DATE field is having datatype datetime, so return me data in this format '2011-12-13 11:12:37.000' and from my application textbox recieve dates and send parameter value in this format'13-12-2011'. how this can be done in better way..that is getting dates between specified dates.

Comment: If your parameters to the query are in varchar, convert them to datetime.

Comment: Ideally you need to convert your textbox string values to proper date(time) type and vice versa. Using textual dates anywhere in sql is bad practise and prone to fail (like you know already :))

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you're on SQL Server 2008 R2, you could just convert everything to the `DATE` format:

```
SELECT * 
FROM dbo.INVOICES INV 
WHERE CAST(INV.CREATED_DATE AS DATE) 
      BETWEEN CAST(@startdate AS DATE) AND CAST(@enddate AS DATE)
```

Since you're using the `DATE` type, you're independent of any dateformat or language settings or any of those tricky features. SQL Server will just compare **dates** - as it should.

And of course: if you make your stored procedure parameters `@startdate` and `@enddate` to be of type `DATE` from the beginning, then you can save yourself those two `CAST` operations, too!

```
SELECT * 
FROM dbo.INVOICES INV 
WHERE CAST(INV.CREATED_DATE AS DATE) BETWEEN @startdate AND @enddate
```

*(and if you made `CREATED_DATE` of type `DATE` - you could even forget about that last `CAST` in the statement, too!)*

Comment: Let's say that `CREATED_DATE` is `datetime` type and there is an index on it, so will SQL Server 2008 use index on `CREATED_DATE` if it's being casted to `date`?

Comment: I would, but I don't have a SQL Server 2008 so I can't, that's why I ask.

Comment: @MichałPowaga: I just tried it - and yes, it appears as if SQL Server **will** indeed use an index on the `DATETIME` column, even if you cast it to `DATE` in your `WHERE` clause.

Answer (score 8):

```
select * from 
invoices inv 
where inv.created_date >= dateadd(dd, 0, datediff(dd, 0, @startdate))
    and inv.created_date < dateadd(dd, 1, datediff(dd, 0, @enddate))
```

First of all, do not [convert](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187928.aspx) your start/end and column's dates to varchar, and if you do so remember that `105` (returns dd-mm-yyyy) is not comparable, `112` (returns yyyymmdd) would be better (when you are interested in date part only). But what I've said it's better not to convert and just compare dates.

**Added**:

And little explanation: `dateadd(dd, 0, datediff(dd, 0, @startdate))` - returns date part only of datetime, `dateadd(dd, 1, datediff(dd, 0, @startdate))` - returns next day date part only.

Query returns all rows for your parameters inclusively (regardless of the hour).

Answer (score 1):

`Default setting is yyyy-MM-dd`

If you use `105` which means you're trying to parse date as format `dmy`, so before executing add below line at the top of your query.

```
SET DATEFORMAT DMY
```